# Angular projects not running due to ng issues

Tags: node.js, angular

I am getting errors in running angular project. Whenever I run any ng command, it throws error (Please check attached screenshot for your reference).

[image]

I have also installed node js but still getting the same error. This issue happened two days ago and all angular projects are giving this error so, according to my understanding, it is a global issue.

Please guide me how to resolve it as I have spent three days on it but still in vain

Thank you

Comment: Have you installed node.js with `Amna` user or as `administrator`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common Windows issue with npm / Angular (Windows is complaining that another process is using those files in some way). Its difficult to really diagnose the exact issue but you could try the following.

> 1) Close all other windows / operations using the Angular project
>
> 2) Open an **Admin** powershell window and re-try the command

These aren't foolproof but tend to work for me when I have these issues. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Let me try out